# How to calculate 7 day average with dates instead of rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below script for calculating the 7 day average new cases using partition and 7 preceding rows. Is there any way to do this by using dates instead? For example, on 2020-01-26, the average is calculated as 0.8 instead of 0.57 if the 7 preceding dates were included in the data. I know it's not a material difference but am just wondering if there is a more accurate way?

```
select country, date, 
    d_confirmed,
    avg(d_confirmed) over(partition by country ORDER BY date rows 6 preceding) As "7_day_avg"
from coronavirusdata_country_combined
where (country = 'Canada' or country = 'Australia')
order by country, date
```

[image: PostgreSQL snapshot]

[image: updated snapshot using range]

Comment: could you please provide some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[postgres prior to v 11 doesn't support RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55171060/postgresql-range-between-interval-10-day-and-current-row) like Oracle does (Oracle can have varying window lengths like "all rows where date column X is between 7 days back from the current row date X and the current row date X"), but if your PG is up to date, then you can adjust your query to say this instead of the rows between:

```
RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL '7 DAY' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

If your PG is older and doesn't you could consider reducing your dataset so it only has one row per day, by summing the individual records - this means your 7 day average can be done with an absolute row count because there is one row per day

```
select 
  country, 
  date, 
  d_confirmed,
  avg(d_confirmed) over(partition by country ORDER BY date rows 6 preceding) As "7_day_avg"
from (
  select country, date, sum(d_confirmed) as d_confirmed 
  from coronavirusdata_country_combined
  group by country, date
) x
where (country = 'Canada' or country = 'Australia')
order by country, date
```

Comment: PostgreSQL *does* support the standard `RANGE` clause.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe and Caius Jard!! I just have a follow up question. Because the data only starts on 22 January, the 7 day average on 26 January is only calculated based on 5 days. Is there any way to calculate the 7 day for 26 January to be between 20-26 January assuming 0 cases for the 2 days not in the data? I've included an updated snapshot in my edit

Comment: @YahNahHah You could `UNION ALL` the original table with 7 artificial very old rows with zero data in a subquery.

Comment: You could also change the average calc so it's SUM/7 rather than AVG

Answer (score 1):

Try using `RANGE` instead of `ROWS` in the `OVER` clause:

```
RANGE BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
```

Then the 7 will denote 7 days rather than 7 rows.